# Working with the SoundClound API without application registration

Tags: soundcloud

At the moment (and for a long time now, as far as I know) there is no way to register an app on SoundCloud. I need to use their API to access public tracks. JavaScript is used. But I always get a 401/403 error response from the server.

As far as I understand, now it is possible to work only after authentication. But for that you need to register the application.

Tell me, is it possible to access API without application registration? I looked through the threads I found, but didn't see a clear answer. SoundCloud support didn't help at all either.